# Problem: modeling philips screw head using modifiers

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to model a screw head using boolean modifiers. I cannot get both tracks subtracted using solidified beveled faces. The second boolean operation fails if both tracks overlap (left) and succeeds if they don't. What is going on ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Boolean ops are very dependant on the meshes. I suggest you upload your model using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and past the result link with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bevel does not work very well in this case, even with only one boolean.

Though, for the second boolean a workaround is to use a mirror instead:

[image]

The empty set as mirror object is located at the sphere center and rotated 45 degrees around Z.

[image]

Comment: Neat solution, many thanks Lemon!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is join both of your boolean objects into one mesh. Then you can apply the modifier. This might also happen because you didn't apply one before using the other.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried that before but in that case the solidify modifier fails on intersecting faces: it looks empty on the inside. I will try to use a mesh which contains and edge where faces intersect.

Comment: Nope, solidified 'cross' does not work either....